# Wait for response using Callisto CustomDialog

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, customdialog, callisto

I have a Windows Store app that uses Callisto toolkit and the CustomDialog control

Inside a FOREACH I show the CustomDialog. The problem is that I need to wait for the users response, I mean, await for the clicked button event (button 1 or button 2)

Is easy with the MessageDialog, you only need to **await dialog.ShowAsync();**

```
<callisto:CustomDialog x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="JustATest" 
    Background="White" BackButtonVisibility="Collapsed" Title="Some title">
    <StackPanel Width="500">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,8" FontSize="14.6667" FontWeight="SemiLight" TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <Run x:Name="txt1" Text="Some random sample text.."/>
        </TextBlock>
        <CheckBox Margin="0,20,0,8" Content="Some checkbox" />

        <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="button 1" Width="80" Margin="0,0,20,0" />
            <Button Content="button 2" Width="80" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</callisto:CustomDialog>
```

Comment: Can you post your foreach part code?

Answer (score 1):

1) [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) - AsyncUI library

2) `using WinRTXamlToolkit.AwaitableUI;`

3)  `public async Task<bool> ShowDialogAsync(....) {
    .......
    this.Dialog.IsOpen = true;
    //add buttons to awaitable
    var buttons = new List<ButtonBase>();
    buttons.Add(btnOK);
    buttons.Add(btnCancel);
    //wait for result
    var clickedButton = await buttons.WaitForClickAsync();
    //close popup
    this.Dialog.IsOpen = false;
    .......
    //return result
    return clickedButton.Name.Contains("btnOK");
  }`

4) `var result = await ShowDialogAsync();`